# How can i load partial view dynamically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, query-string, asp.net-mvc-partialview

How can i load partial view dynamically?I tried to use with querystring as below but i got error when runtime.

**My code:**

```
@Html.Partial("_Sample?id=3")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
@Html.Action("Sample", "Users", new { UserId = 1 })
```

And in your `UsersController`:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Sample(int UserId) 
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: i want to retrieve data on database inside this partial view.Is correct way this approach?

Comment: By the way if there is any confusion between `@Html.Partial` and `@Html.Action` check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766554/mvc-html-partial-or-html-action