# Retrieve partial view data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have menu and using this I'm rendering partial view in my index page

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("week I", "firstWeekWinners", new
{

}, new AjaxOptions()
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    UpdateTargetId = "weeWinnersDIv",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
}, new { @class = "weekDays wactive" })
```

and there's partial view controller:

```
 public PartialViewResult firstWeekWinners()
    {
        ViewBag.laptopWinners = db.firstWeekLaptopWinner().ToList();
        ViewBag.tabWinners = db.firstWeekGalaxyWinner().ToList();
        ViewBag.ipodWinners = db.firstWeekIpodWinner().ToList();
        ViewBag.headPhonesWinners = db.firstWeekHeadPhonesWinner().ToList();
        ViewBag.kingstonWinners = db.firstWeekkingstonUsbWinner().ToList();

        return PartialView();
    }
```

and partial view:

```
  @if (ViewBag.laptopWinners != null)
{
    <div class="winnersPrizeOverflow">
        <div class="winnersPrizePic"></div>
        <div class="winnersAllprizeLeft"><p>12</p></div>
    </div>
    foreach (var q in ViewBag.laptopWinners)
    {
        <span>@q.firstName</span>
        <br />
        <span>@q.lastName</span>
        <br />
        <span>@q.fbId</span>
        <br />
        <span>@q.sumOfBids</span>
        <br />
    }
}
```

If I'll click to this *ajax.actionlink* it renders this view but without this if I'll put `@Html.Partial("firstWeekWinners")` it doesn't goes in controller to retrieve my data. 
How can I improve that?

Comment: You need `@Html.Action("firstWeekWinners")` to call a controller method that returns a partial view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke write it as answer. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call your `firstWeekWinners` method use `@Html.Action()`, not `@Html.Partial()`

```
@Html.Action("firstWeekWinners")
```

[Refer to the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703423%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for the various overloads, and these [question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766554/mvc-html-partial-or-html-action) explaining the differences and usage.