# Bind viewmodel to partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a model, which can represent 3 categories. I want in my view, make 3 different tables for each category with relevant fields. I think for this I need to use partial view with viewmodel for each category.

So my main model is "Ad", which have 3 sub viewmodels (Realty, Auto and Service).
Here the example how I implement Realty action on my home controller:

```
public ActionResult Realty()
    {
        var ads = db.Ads.Include(a => a.Realty);
        var vm = new List<RealtyViewModel>();

        foreach (var ad in ads)
        {
            vm.Add(new RealtyViewModel
            {
                Title = ad.Title,
                Descirpiton = ad.Descirpiton,
                Type = ad.Realty.Type,
                NumberOfRooms = ad.Realty.NumberOfRooms
            });
        }

        return PartialView(vm);
    }
```

Then my partial view, looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<OGAS.Areas.Category.ViewModels.RealtyViewModel>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Type)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descirpiton)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NumberOfRooms)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descirpiton)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumberOfRooms)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Then in my Index page (without using any models), I call partial view like this:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("Realty");}
```

But then I'm getting following error:

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_gdyh352c.dll but was not handled in user code

Could you please advise if this approach is good (calling 3 vms), if yes how to implement this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `@{Html.RenderPartial("Realty");}` and use `@Html.Action("Realty")` in this case, as you need to call back to the controller action, in order to create the model for the partial view.

See [MVC Html.Partial or Html.Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766554/mvc-html-partial-or-html-action) for more information.

Comment: Big thanks, this works. Can you please advise I have a doubt, is this approach good (from performance standpoint), I'll end up by calling 3 Html.Action methods with 3 different vm.

Comment: Its quite common approach with MVC. You are still loading the same data - you will need to call it from the controller at some point. Your other option is to create 1 large view model for the main view and use e.g. `@Html.Partial("_partialName", model.Realty)`

Answer (score 1):

Use this, for .net core and mvc. @Html.Action has been removed from .net core

```
 @await Html.PartialAsync("_YourPartialViewName", YourModel)
```

Comment: How do you bind YourModel to something then? With RenderAction() you were able to call a specific controller method to populate the model. I can't understand how to do this now, in .NET Core without the action() method.